# Integrating an inner product by parts

Tags: differential-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I am trying to integrate the following:

$$ \int \langle F, -(\partial_u \kappa) T\rangle du $$

where $F: S^1 \times [0,T) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a simple closed plane curve given
by spatial parameter $u$ (mod $2\pi$) and time parameter $t$. The paper I
am reading states that integrating the above by parts yields:

$$ \int \langle \partial_u F, \kappa T\rangle + \langle F, \kappa \partial_u T\rangle du $$

I am not even sure how you would integrate an inner product, let alone integrate one by parts. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Thought I would share some of the work I have done here. The closest I have come to solving this is getting the equation

$$ \partial_u \langle F, \kappa T\rangle = \langle \partial_u F, \kappa T\rangle + \langle F, (\partial_u \kappa)T\rangle + \langle F,\kappa\partial_u T\rangle $$

which gives us:

$$  \langle F, -(\partial_u \kappa)T\rangle + \partial_u \langle F, \kappa T\rangle = \langle \partial_u F, \kappa T\rangle +  + \langle F,\kappa\partial_u T\rangle $$

But I have an extra term and haven't done any integration.

2nd edit: Thought I would link the paper just in case anyone wanted to get some more context. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214439902. Page 7 Lemma 3.1.7

Comment: Your work looks good.  Now take integrals of everything.  Do you know the general [Stokes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem)?

Comment: If I take the integral of that equation do I not end up with an extra term? (Namely $\partial_u \langle F,\kappa T\rangle$).

Comment: Yes, but that extra integral equals zero (by Stokes' Theorem).

Comment: I am not very familiar with differential forms sorry. What would be $\omega$ in this case? (Following the notation from the wiki page you linked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a simple closed curve in the plane $F \colon \mathbb{S}^1 \times I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that is evolving in time $t \in I$ according to the heat equation.  We are letting $u$ denote the spatial parameter.  We let $T$ and $N$ be the unit tangent and inward-pointing normal vectors, respectively.

The OP has correctly calculated that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \langle F, \kappa T \rangle = \left\langle \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}, \kappa T\right\rangle + \left\langle F, \frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial u} T \right\rangle + \left\langle F, \kappa \frac{\partial T}{\partial u} \right \rangle\!,$$
whence
$$\left\langle F, -\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial u} T \right\rangle  = - \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \langle F, \kappa T\rangle + \left\langle \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}, \kappa T\right\rangle + \left\langle F, \kappa \frac{\partial T}{\partial u} \right \rangle\!,$$
whence
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left\langle F, -\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial u} T \right\rangle du  = - \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \langle F, \kappa T\rangle\, du + \int_0^{2\pi}\left\langle \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}, \kappa T\right\rangle du + \int_0^{2\pi}\left\langle F, \kappa \frac{\partial T}{\partial u} \right \rangle du.$$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the first integral on the right side is zero (because we're working with a simple closed curve):
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \langle F, \kappa T\rangle\, du = \left. \frac{}{} \langle F, \kappa T\rangle \right|^{2\pi}_0 = \langle F(2\pi), \kappa(2\pi)T(2\pi) \rangle - \langle F(0), \kappa(0)T(0) \rangle = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I didn't realize I almost had it. Also, you are using $\tau$ sometimes. Do you mean $T$?

Comment: Yes, that was a consistent typo; it's fixed now.